Clickable Jira hyperlink in GitHub pull request title
I am facing issues while creating a clickable link in GitHub pull request title which redirects to Jira issue.
I am getting the following plain text (not link) in the PR title:

APS-4018 test1 (Jira: [APS-4018](https://jira-domain.net/browse/APS-4018)) #36

I have added a workflow jira-link-in-pr.yml:
name: Add Jira Link to PR Title

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, edited, synchronize] # Trigger on PR creation or updates

jobs:
  update-pr-title:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Step 1: Extract Jira issue key from the PR title
      - name: Extract Jira Issue Key
        id: extract_key
        run: |
          ISSUE_KEY=$(echo "${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}" | grep -oE '[A-Z]+-[0-9]+')
          if [ -z "$ISSUE_KEY" ]; then
            echo "No Jira issue key found in the PR title"
            echo "key=none" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          else
            echo "Found Jira issue key: $ISSUE_KEY"
            echo "key=$ISSUE_KEY" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          fi

      # Step 2: Update the PR title to include the Jira link
      - name: Update PR Title with Jira Link
        if: env.key != 'none'
        run: |
          JIRA_URL="https://jira-domain.net/browse/${key}"
          # Check if the PR title already contains the Jira link to avoid duplication
          if [[ "${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}" != *"${JIRA_URL}"* ]]; then
            NEW_TITLE="${{ github.event.pull_request.title }} (Jira: [${key}](${JIRA_URL}))"
            curl -X PATCH \
                 -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
                 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                 -d "{\"title\": \"${NEW_TITLE}\"}" \
                 ${{ github.event.pull_request.url }}
          else
            echo "Jira link is already present in the PR title."
          fi

inside .github/workflows.
How can I achieve this:

My PR title has clickable link to Jira issue; and
PR fails if the issue does not exist?


You can't achieve 1; Markdown is only supported in the body, not the title.
